# FQDN for Send/Receive Connectors in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

We recently switched ISP's and I'm trying to make sure there are no mail flow problems.  I noticed under my `Organization` -> `Hub Transport` -> `Send Connectors` that my send connector FQDN setting is the hostname and domain of my email server. It is also the same for the receive connectors under `Server Config` -> `Hub Transport`.  Should it be using my email servers `hostname.domainname.com` or should it be using my MX record address `mail.domainname.com`.

Would this cause issues?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the connectors set up both ways on our clients.  I personally prefer to use the mail.domain.com for the base send/receive connectors and leave the internal for relays and such, but to my knowledge it has never caused an issue either way.